# Scroller "scroll,drag,start" event's parameters

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In Tizen 4.0, I'm using a scroller which provides multiple events when it's being scrolled, or dragged.

There is this event: "**scroll,drag,start**", and its callback:

```
static void scrollDragStart(void* data, Evas_Object* obj, void *event_info) { }
```

My question is simple: is there any way to determine the direction of the scroller's dragging?

(I know there are events with direction like "*scroll,up*", but it comes later after the drag event.)

Comment: There seems to be no way the user to know the direction of the scroller when the drag start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such information is not provided through arguments directly.
(as you already know) if you want to know it, use 'scroll,[direction]' callback.

I guess that something like below works,
first, store scroller position whenever it moves.
second, when the callback has invoked, calculate diff between stored position with  current position of the scroller.